# ReactJS - Can I open open a Modal from different component

Tags: reactjs, simplemodal

I am trying to call a model in "model.js" by onClick a button from another component (list.js) , just wonder if I have missed any step please see below:

model.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Model extends React.Component{

 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    //code inside the Model etc...  
    <Button onClick={this.submit.bind(this)}>Submit</Button>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Model;
```

list.js

```
import Model from './model';
class List extends React.Component{
 render(){

  constructor() {
  super();

   this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
   this.state = {
     open: false
   }
  }

  toggleModal() {
   this.setState({
   open: this.state.open
   });
  }

return(
 <div>
  <Button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Add</Button>
 </div>
 <div>
  <Model open={this.state.open} toggleModal={this.toggleModal}/>
 </div>
  )
 }
}

export default List;
```

I have tried many ways to change the event handler code in List , but it still doesnt work.

That would be much appreciate if you guys could give me a hand and point out where the problems are, so that i can move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you changing the state `open` value to either true or false

```
this.setState({
   open: this.state.open
});
```

The above code will always set the value as `false`. Maybe what you could do is `!this.state.open`

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You definetely miss the exclamation mark, because as for now, you will always assign `false` value when clicking the button - modal won't show up.

```
this.setState({
  open: !this.state.open
});
```